# VBA Export Excel to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm getting a '1004' error when running this macro.

```
Sub macro_PDF()

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
     Type:=xlTypePDF, _
     FileName:="/Users/username/Desktop/tests/filename.pdf", _
     OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Image of the Error

[image]

This same code works fine if the name of the file is "PDF.pdf". It seems like I can only export the PDF with the name "PDF.pdf".

The code below returns no errors. Why is this happening?

```
Sub macro_PDF()

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
     Type:=xlTypePDF, _
     FileName:="/Users/username/Desktop/tests/pdf.pdf", _
     OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: So add another bit of code to rename the pdf.pdf after it has been exported...

Comment: I've only ever used Windows, but can you start a filepath with a forward slash like that on a Mac?

Comment: @dwirony the forward slash works fine in Mac. The file "PDF.pdf" was created manually before the macro was run – while "Filename.pdf" doesn't exist. Is there anything in the Document properties that could be causing the error?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not just that filename.pdf is open somewhere?

Comment: @RichardBJ initially I also thought about that. I checked it and all files are closed

Comment: are you really trying `filename`? or is that a placeholder for some other name? If so, what is the other name? If not, try something like `myFile.pdf`?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman `filename.pdf` is the actual name I gave to the new file. Now I also tried with your suggestion `myFile.pdf` and the same error was returned. Is it possible that error is caused by user permissions in my laptop? The laptop belongs to me and I'm using the only account that's available.

Comment: The reason why I'm thinking about permissions is because I can use this code to overwrite an existing file but not to create a new one. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have run/debugged this a few times on my PC and of course, the name of the file makes no difference. Filename.pdf exports just fine. This error seems to have two potential causes. (1) Is that the file path itself was not found, the other (2) is that the file already exists. So check that first like this:

```
Sub macro_PDF()
Filename = "c:/fmob/filename.pdf"
If Dir(Filename) <> vbNullString Then
    Kill Filename
End If
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=Filename, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

I encountered one situation where the macro could not write the file even after deleting longhand (i.e., using explorer) and this seems to have resulted from a bug of some sort with PDF Acrobat not closing all file handles correctly.  Presumably rebooting would fix that.

Comment: I really liked the idea about adding the `Dir`command.
I copied and pasted your code to test it. The `Dir` command is not finding the file – I guess that there's an issue with the route – so I added the following code to make sure i'm pointing to the right file. However it's still not working right :-(
`Dim path As String
 Dim FileName As String
         
       path = ThisWorkbook.path
       FileName = "filename.pdf"
         
         If Dir(path & FileName) <> vbNullString Then
             Kill (path & "/" & FileName)
         End If `

Comment: I found that in a Mac I have to replace the slashes ("/") by colons (":") inside `Filename.path`. The macro always creates a new PDF or it overwrites the existing file. The `Kill Filename`never works. I don't understand why the same code creates a new file in the destination folder but can't find that file if it already exists. any help? thnx